# Sending current object array index context to function

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a list of tabs and want to set each tabs title dynamically depending on the result of some function call. Imagine the following array:

```
const tabs = [{
    active: true,
    canShow: true,
    disabled: false,
    title: this._assignTitle(...)
}, {
    active: false,
    canShow: false,
    disabled: true,
    title: this._assignTitle(...)
}, {
    active: false,
    canShow: true,
    disabled: false,
    title: this._assignTitle(...)
}];
```

Let's say the title was dependent on the current indexes properties `(active, canShow, disabled)`. Would there be a way to send the current object in the array to the function I'm calling?

Maybe the `_assignTitle(...)` function can take a parameter like `currentTab`.

So if the first `_assignTitle(currentTab)` were to be called, I'd expect `currentTab` to be an object containing:

```
{
    active: true,
    canShow: true,
    disabled: false,
    title: this (?)
}
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you'd want to recalculate the tab titles based on changes to the properties, as a result of user interaction.  Even if once off, this is still valid perhaps.

You can use map to create a new array based off the initial or current state.

There is no need to use 'this', but this example could be modified as such if you felt the need (if tabs had more functionality you'd like to encapsulate within a class/prototype)

```js
function getTitle(tab) {
  // calculate the title based on properties
  return tab.canShow ? 'show' : 'no show'
}

function addTitle(tab) {
  // take the existing tab, returning new tab with computed title
  return Object.assign({}, tab, { title: getTitle(tab) })
}

const tabs = [{
    active: true,
    canShow: true,
    disabled: false,
}, {
    active: false,
    canShow: false,
    disabled: true,
}, {
    active: false,
    canShow: true,
    disabled: false,
}].map(addTitle)

console.log(tabs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach it would be to pre-process the array:

```
const setup = tabs => {
  tabs.forEach(t => {
    // Calculate your result here
    t.title = '';
  });
  return tabs;
};

const tabs = setup([{
    active: true,
    canShow: true,
    disabled: false
}, {
    active: false,
    canShow: false,
    disabled: true
}, {
    active: false,
    canShow: true,
    disabled: false
}]);
```

Comment: I’d send the current index as, for example, `this.tabs[0]` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by send? Are you saying you need to compute the titles after the initialization?

Answer (score -1):

Your tabs array is an array of objects. in each object you are setting a property title to be a function that doesn't exist. Using this._assignTitle would only work if a function existed called assignTitle in each object, and still it's a little awkward. It would perhaps better do define the function outside of your array and then set title to the result of that function.

```
    var assignTitle = function(currentTab){
    return "title";
    }
const tabs = [{
    active: true,
    canShow: true,
    disabled: false,
    title: assignTitle(true,true,false)
}, {
    active: false,
    canShow: false,
    disabled: true,
    title: assignTitle(false,false,true)
}, {
    active: false,
    canShow: true,
    disabled: false,
    title: assignTitle(false,true,false)
}];

console.log(tabs);
```

Comment: This is neat, I’m going to give this a go

Comment: Sorry, you can't have semicolons inside object definitions. Just remove them. and the function needs to be declared before tabs. I have changed my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Given the code you posted, The `this` being passed to `assignTitle` is not the current tab.

Comment: Oh it's the window

Comment: perhaps its best to know what user 5482 means to do to the title.